# How would I switch between forms without opening a new window? C# MSVB

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I might be going about this the wrong way, but I'm trying to create a form that will include a single button, for instance "Enter".  When "Enter" is clicked, I want the form to then display the contents of form 2, which might include more buttons and/or a textbox, etc.  I want to do all this without ever opening or closing a form.

Comment: A form == a window (unless using MDI children).

Comment: you can use an overlaying panel to display when enter is clicked. this panel will contain the form2 attributes (not neat, but working)

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using panels and showing the one you currently need, hiding the others.

Comment: Thank you.  All I needed was that key word.  Checking out panel tutorials now, that's all I needed.

Comment: @Tim, that's a good positive attitude to have when learning.  Much better than simply being handed a full code snippet and copy and pasting!

Answer (score 3):

Panels will definitly fullfil what you are looking for. And if you have many functionlality with in forms, UserControls will cretainly serve you better. Add and remove whichever you want. You can have separate constructors for every user control. I personally and highly recommend UserControls.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Totally agree. The Panels might be just enough in this given small example, but for any bigger application UserControls will be the right choice.

Answer (score 1):

I think changeing visibility of forms will solve your problem.

Comment: which forms you are talking about.........OP is having just one form and he want to stick to that only, so no question of changing visibility of any thing related to form

Comment: Tim Schaeppi said :"I want the form to then display the contents of form 2"

Comment: yep....display the contents of form2 but not in form2. he want just the content, not a new form. and thats what others are suggesting....put the contents of form2 in a panel and play with the visibilty of panel rather than creating all new form

Comment: ı think he can open both forms initially and then change only visibility.

Comment: yes he can......but we are only looking for a better and effective solution. As if there are 10 forms, 10 processes will be running in the processor and if 1 form and 10 panels, only 1 process and will be very fast. there are other many benifits of using panels over a hidden form. changing visibility of forms will cause a glitch also